# Different methods of finding the area of an irregular shape

Tags: geometry

I currently know of 3 methods of calculating the area of an irregular shape.
 - Pick's theorem
 - Integration by bounded area of two functions
 - Monte Carlo's method

Are there any other methods of finding area of irregular shapes?
Thank you.

Comment: You could use Green's theorem, find the area of the shape using a line integral around it's perimeter. This could be good for polygons.

Comment: The [Shoelace Formula/Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula) allows you to find the area of any simple polygon given coordinates of its vertices. It's really just a special case of [Green's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem), which uses vector calculus to relate areas to perimeters.

Comment: Ah, that's pretty cool! I guess you don't need Green's theorem when an algebraic alternative of it exists.

Comment: Triangulate and use the determinant to compute the area of each triangle.

Comment: You could cut the area from a piece of cardboard (of known uniform density) and weigh it